# how to get dragged event in JQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i am using this jquery to make a drag and drop sortable list. 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
how i can catch the dragged event of elements ?

```
<script>
```

> $(document).ready(function() {
>       $("#sortable").sortable();
>     });

```
</script>
```

please help me.am not familiar with jquery.thanks in advance..i need to get the id of dragged element.

Comment: this post helped me to catch the drag event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148145/drag-event-for-jquery-ui-sortable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to get the ID of the dragged element:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    stop: function(ui, event){
        var id = event.item.attr('id');
        alert(id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to previous answer but I used deactivate to capture the event after a sorting has been done

**jQuery:**

```
$('.week').sortable({
  deactivate: function (ui,e) {
    console.log(e.item.attr('id'));
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), you might use `start` or `activate` events.