# Does jQuery scrollTop() accept a callback function?

Tags: jquery

In the below sample code, a callback function is used as the argument to the scrollTop().

http://jsfiddle.net/xjrLN/2/

What are parameters' values i and v of the callback?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var is_dragging = false;

    $( 'ul' ).disableSelection().sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        start: function() { is_dragging = true },
        stop: function() { is_dragging = false }
    }).mousemove( function( e ) {
        if( is_dragging ) {
           // **** What are parameters' values i and v of the callback? *****
            $( 'ul' ).scrollTop(function(i, v) {
                var h = $( 'ul' ).height();
                var y = e.clientY - h / 2;
                return v + y * 0.1;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The sample code is from the post
[Scrolling a sortable/dragable item's parent container when its border is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029709/scrolling-a-sortable-dragable-items-parent-container-when-its-border-is-reached)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is not a callback function. A callback to scrollTop() would trigger after setting a value to ensure synchronous execution (for instance in animate()). Instead of setting a value, e.g. `$('ul').scollTop('20');` a function is used to calculate a value, which is then returned.

Upon investigation and with feedback on the jQuery forums, it has become clear that `i` returns the index of the current element in the set of the jQuery selector, and `v` returns the current value of `scrollTop()` for that element.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('body').scrollTop(function(i, v) {
    console.log(i + ' ' + v);
    // i == index of current element in the selector
    // (zero-based of course)
    // (v == $('body').scrollTop())
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600vh;
  width: 600vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But the function is really called, pls see my updated code, the v and i are output to the console. http://jsfiddle.net/xjrLN/131/