# Saving a reordered List item from an MVC View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model which binds to a 'TreasureHuntDetails' object, which contains a list of clues. Here's part of the data model for it.

```
    public TreasureHuntDetails()
    {
        Clues = new List<Clue>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TreasureHuntId { get; set; }

    public List<Clue> Clues { get; set; }
```

On the page, I have a table. A foreach loop iterates through the list of clues to add them to the table, e.g.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Clues.Count; i++)
```

The table elements inside the for loop are quite large, but here's an example of one of the table element columns:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Clues[i].Location)</td>
```

All well and good so far. Then I'm using JQuery UI to allow the items of the table to be reordered using drag and drop, like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#clueTable tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
        });
        </script>
```

All well and good, I can drag and drop the elements.

The problem  is that I don't know how to save the new order of elements and save them back to the database.

The first thing I tried was simply passing the list of clues to a controller method, but I found that once the list of clues reached the controller method, it was always null.

For example:

```
@Url.Action("ViewCluePage", @Model.Clues)
```

Even if I send the whole @Model, list of clues within is always null. Removing the new list instantiation from the constructor of the data model didn't solve this problem.

Another thing I tried was wrapping the whole table into a HTML form, but still the list of clues remains null.

So basically, this question is really two questions:

1) Why is the list of clues always null after sending the model object to a controller.

2) How to save the new order of the list of items?

UPDATE: As per suggestion by @recursive, I see where I made an error when trying to submit the clue elements to the HTML form.

I used this outside the for loop which iterated over the clue elements:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Clues)
```

I had to add the HiddenFor lines inside of the for loop (for each clue item), and for EACH property of the clue item, e.g.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Clues[i].Id)
```

So that would be one step forward to be able to get the list items sent to the controller, but I think I still need code that will reflect the new order of the clue items when sent to the controller. Currently, on rearranging the order of the elements on screen using the JQuery sortable() method, this doesn't change the order of the elements as they are stored in the data model binded to the view (@Model.Clues).

Comment: In order for the the new list to make it back to the controller action, the generated html for the list items must contain some for element like `<input type="hidden">`.  What does your list item html look like?  You can add it to your question.

Comment: Did my answer help you out at all? Can you accept the answer if it did?

Comment: Yep it did thanks, it got me on the right path so I've upvoted your answer. I've ended up with quite a different implementation though so I'm going to post that up later.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) As @resursive said in his comment, you need to have hidden elements on the page that map to properties in your `Clue` class.

2) As for persisting the order of clues, you'll need to add a column to your database that holds the position of each clue in the list and add the position property to your class. So your class would need to include

```
public int Position {get;set;}
```

which should pull from the database when the page is created. Then just before rendering the page, you should reorder the clue list based on the Position variable.

Edit: Use jquery's sortable attribute. [Check out this thread for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148145/drag-event-for-jquery-ui-sortable) In the stop drag event (or right before your submit), loop through each of your draggable objects and set the value of each of the hidden Position properties of your objects.

```
var positionIndex = 0;
$('.draggableObjectClass).each(function () {
    $(this).find('input[id$=_Position]').val(positionIndex++);
});
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that I have to refactor a lot of code to get this to work across the web application.

Comment: Also, how do I actually get the new positions from the view? With your suggestion for (1) I can successfully send the list of clues to the controller, but the original order is maintained - the new order is not reflected.

Comment: jquery's `each` passes an index to the callback so no need to track it in `positionIndex`. Great answer though.. just used this!

Answer (score 0):

> but I think I still need code that will reflect the new order of the clue items when sent to the controller.

You won't, as you are now iterating over them in a `for` loop, they will be indexed in the order that you sent them to the view. Your order must already be maintained.

Comment: Rearranging the order of the clue elements doesn't change the order that they are stored in the data model though...

Comment: @CiaranG Very true, unless you're changing it?

Comment: After rearranging the elements and sending the list of clues to the controller, the clue elements are still in their original order... I need to figure out a way for the Model to pick up on the new order of elements.

Comment: @CiaranG You'll need to call `ModelState.Clear()` to do that. By default it uses the `ModelState` values (what was passed to the view originally).

Comment: @CiaranG In your post action before you use your model. Basically it holds everything in the model that was sent to the view, clearing it means that the model values passed in from the view are used.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advice from the answers posted here already, I came up with the following solution.

With already having this method in place to implement the drag and drop reordering of the UI elements,

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#clueTable tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
    });
```

I needed a way to be able read the in the new order of items and send it to the MVC controller. To do this I used the Razor @Html.AttributeEncode method to write the Id's of each item to a column on each row of the table, like this:

```
<td class="Ids" id="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Clues[i].Id)">@{var number = i + 1; @number}</td>
```

(This is wrapped around a for loop which iterates through the list of items.)

Then, I created the following Javascript function, which is invoked from a 'SaveNewOrder' button I placed above my table of elements (the user presses this once they have finished reordering the items on the table):

```
    function getNewOrder()
    {
        var positions = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < $('.Ids').length; i++)
        {
            positions[i] = $('.Ids')[i].id;
        }
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("ReorderClues", "Clues")",
                data:{ treasureHuntDetails: $("form").serialize(), ids: JSON.stringify(positions) }
                contentType:'application/json'
            }).done(function()
            {
                 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Clues", Model)';  
            }).   
    }
```

What this is does is reads the Id elements from each of the table items, and writes them into the array - so this array contains the NEW order of Id's. The data model containing the items doesn't change after reordering the table elements, hence why this was necessary.

It then uses a JQuery Ajax method to invoke a 'ReOrderClues' method on my 'Clues' MVC controller, passing a serialised version of the data model (containing a list of the clue items in the original order) and an array containing a list of the clue Id's in the new order. When the result is returned from the controller (.done), I invoke a controller which refreshes the page elements.

So rather than having to maintain a position value associated with each clue (which would involve significant refactoring elsewhere in the code), what I'm doing is swapping the contents of the clues around to reflect the new order, but keeping the Id's in the same position.

This is how I achieved that using an MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReorderClues(TreasureHuntDetails treasureHuntDetails, int[] ids)
{
    using (var db = new TreasureHuntDB())
    {
        var clues = treasureHuntDetails.Clues;
        var newClues = NewOrderList(clues, ids);

        // Save the changes of each clue
        for (var i = 0; i < newClues.Count;i++ )
        {
            db.Entry(clues[i]).CurrentValues.SetValues(newClues[i]);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        treasureHuntDetails.Clues = newClues;
        TempData["Success"] = "Clues reordered";
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Clues", treasureHuntDetails);
}

public List<Clue> NewOrderList(List<Clue> clues, int[] ids)
{
    var newClueOrder = new List<Clue>();

    // For each ID in the given order
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
    {
        // Get the original clue that matches the given ID
        var clue = clues.First(clue1 => clue1.Id == ids[i]);

        var newClue = Clue.Clone(clue);

        // Add the clue to the new list. 
        newClueOrder.Add(newClue);

        // Retain the ID of the clue 
        newClueOrder[i].Id = clues[newClueOrder.Count - 1].Id;
    }

    return newClueOrder;
}
```

In the above code snippet, TreasureHuntDB is my Entity Framework database context.